# How come my font face looks different on the web than it does in the ttf/woff files?

Tags: css, font-face

[This is what the font should look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqfl2.png)
[Here's what the font looks like in the .ttf file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYGUu.png)
[And this is what the font looks like on my website.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK0xb.png)

```css
#top {
    margin:             30px 30px 0px 150px;
    border:             3px solid maroon;
    text-align:       center;
    height:             130px;
    background:     url(text/dumbledore.gif) right no-repeat, url(text/gandalf.gif) left no-repeat, url(text/tenor.gif) center;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Beyond Wonderland';
    src: url('fonts/BeyondWonderland.eot');
    src: url('fonts/BeyondWonderland.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/BeyondWonderland.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/BeyondWonderland.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/BeyondWonderland.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/BeyondWonderland.svg#BeyondWonderland') format('svg');
    font-weight:  normal;
    font-style:   normal;
}

h1#title-text {
  font-family:  'Beyond Wonderland';
  border:       none;
  font-size:    450%;
  width:        100%;
  text-shadow:  1px white;
  color:        black;
  text-align:   center;
  padding:      20px 0px 20px 0px;
  margin:       auto;
}
```

```html
    <div id="top">
        <h1 id="title-text" title="You are viewing the home page">Welcome to the Erevrast Home Page!</h1>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `text-shadow` applies to even the faintest line in the font, so every smudge/scrape in the artistic font will end up with a 1 pixel white shadow. Try removing `text-shadow: 1px white;`.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining the `src` of the font twice in CSS. seperating it by commas will show the font after it if it can't be loaded. Example:

```
src: url(nonexistentfont.ttf), Arial;
```

Will show the font "Arial" because the other font couldn't be loaded.

Try this

```css
#top {
    margin: 30px 30px 0px 150px;
    border: 3px solid maroon;
    text-align: center;
    height: 130px;
    background: url(text/dumbledore.gif) right no-repeat, url(text/gandalf.gif) left no-repeat, url(text/tenor.gif) center;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Beyond Wonderland';
    src: url(fonts/BeyondWonderland.eot), url(fonts/BeyondWonderland.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'), url(fonts/BeyondWonderland.woff2') format('woff2'), url('fonts/BeyondWonderland.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/BeyondWonderland.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/BeyondWonderland.svg#BeyondWonderland') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1#title-text {
  font-family:  'Beyond Wonderland';
  border:       none;
  font-size:    450%;
  width:        100%;
  text-shadow:  1px white;
  color:        black;
  text-align:   center;
  padding:      20px 0px 20px 0px;
  margin:       auto;
}
```

```html
    <div id="top">
        <h1 id="title-text" title="You are viewing the home page">Welcome to the Erevrast Home Page!</h1>
    </div>
```